# gaussian mixture based segmentation

Tags: matlab, gaussian, image-segmentation

I have an image with four different kinds of colors - dark blue, light blue, an even lighter blue - background and white - background. I'd like to segment only the first two categories

```
bG= mat2gray(image);
his=imhist(bG);
sai = gmdistribution.fit(his,4);
m1=sai.mu(1);
v1=sai.Sigma(1);
m2=sai.mu(2);
v2=sai.Sigma(2);

imt=bG<m2+v2;
figure;
imagesc(~imt);
```

I get an Image with all pixels 1. The bG image matrix had values less than 1 but the mean and variance of each gaussian was way higher.

From what I understood, bG is an image matrix and hence will have intensity values. so all the values here are less than 1.

but the means of four guassians are:  0.8604    0.976    2.9182    6.6377. These don't seem to be intensities and so when I tried to get all the pixels in the image less than second mean, all the pixels passed the test. There is something that I am missing here. Can any one help me segment dark blue and light blue cells based on Gaussian mixture. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that sai.mu(1) < sai.mu(2) < sai.mu(3) etc. So for all you know mu(2) could correspond to white, in which case m2+v2 will be greater than 1, and all the pixels will pass the test. I would simply use sai.cluster(bG(:)), find the two lowest mus, and concatenate the clusters corresponding to the two smallest mus, like so:

```
sai = gmdistribution.fit(his,4);

mus = [sai.mu(1),sai.mu(2),sai.mu(3),sai.mu(4)];
[~,sortmus] = sort(mus);

clusters = sai.cluster(bG(:));
bGclustered = clusters == sortmus(1) | clusters == sortmus(2);

subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(bG)
subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(reshape(bGclustered,size(bG)))
```

Comment: Patrick, could you please check the edit I made in the question. Thanks!